# Gerar números aleatórios em java, armazenar em um vetor e ordená-los

Tags: java, algoritmo, random

Preciso gerar 100000 números, armazená-los em um vetor e ordená-los utilizando o algoritmo BubbleSort, está aparecendo o erro "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at testaSort.main(testaSort.java:8)"
```

Código abaixo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;


    public class testaSort {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int i;
            long inicio;
            long fim;
            double tempo;
            int[] vetor = new int [100000];
            int intervaloInicial = 0;
            int intervaloFinal = 100000;
            for (i=0 ; i < vetor.length; i++)
            {
                vetor [i] = getRandomNumberRange(intervaloInicial , intervaloFinal);
                System.out.println(vetor[i]);}
            }
            private static int getRandomNumberRange(int min, int max)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                return r.ints (min,(max+1)).limit(1).findFirst().getAsInt();
            }


            //BubbleSort
            System.out.println("--Bubblesort--");
            inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Sort.bubbleSort(vetor);
            fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.printf("%.3f ms%n", (fim - inicio) / 1000d);
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa mensagem indica que há erros de sintaxe que impedem o seu código de ser compilado.

Por exemplo, o bloco de código abaixo do comentário `//BubbleSort` está fora de um método. Além disso, você não implementou o algoritmo do Bubble Sort no seu código e há chaves sem fechamento.

Eu dei uma arrumada no seu código. O Bubble Sort que eu implementei foi retirado desse site: [BubbleSort em Java e em C](https://www.blogcyberini.com/2018/02/bubble-sort.html)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class testaSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        long inicio;
        long fim;
        //double tempo;
        int[] vetor = new int[100000];
        int intervaloInicial = 0;
        int intervaloFinal = 100000;
        for (i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            vetor[i] = getRandomNumberRange(intervaloInicial, intervaloFinal);
            System.out.println(vetor[i]);
        }
        //BubbleSort
        System.out.println("--Bubblesort--");
        inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        bubbleSort(vetor);
        fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("%.3f ms%n", (fim - inicio) / 1000d);
    }

    private static int getRandomNumberRange(int min, int max) {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.ints(min, (max + 1)).limit(1).findFirst().getAsInt();
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] a){
        if(a == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("The array doesn't exist.");
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length - i - 1; j++){
                if(a[j] > a[j + 1]){
                    int temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de saída do seu programa:

```
65737
37487
85573
87395
...
68212
65816
25052
--Bubblesort--
23,910 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não está utilizando a variável "tempo". Então ela pode ser exluída.

Para o sort, você pode fazer seu próprio algorítmo de bublle sort ou usar o Arrays.sort() - esse não usa bubble sort.

Algorítmo bubble (se quiser ordenar ao contrário é só inverter o for):

```
private void bubbleSort(int[] vetor) {
    int aux;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
            if(vetor[j] > vetor[j + 1]){
                aux = vetor[j];
                vetor[j] = vetor[j+1];
                vetor[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adaptando seu código:

```
public class testaSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        long inicio;
        long fim;
        int[] vetor = new int[100000];
        int intervaloInicial = 0;
        int intervaloFinal = 100000;
        for (i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            vetor[i] = getRandomNumberRange(intervaloInicial, intervaloFinal);
            System.out.println(vetor[i]);
        }
        // BubbleSort
        System.out.println("--Bubblesort--");
        inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Arrays.sort(vetor);
        bubbleSort(vetor);
        fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("%.3f ms%n", (fim - inicio) / 1000d);
    }

    private void bubbleSort(int[] vetor) {
        int aux;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (vetor[j] > vetor[j + 1]) {
                    aux = vetor[j];
                    vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];
                    vetor[j + 1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```